# Access factory which return baseClass* , from the baseClass Function itself

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, visual-c++

I have a scenario where I need to call a factory which returns baseClass * from a function of baseClass itself

I have a function() which is common for all the child class. So I decided to define that function in base class, and the derived class then can inherit from it. Now in that function we need to call a factory which returns the BaseClass*.

```
class BaseClass{
public:
virtual bool someFunc(){
  baseClass *var = Factory::GetObject(1);
  // do some processing on var
}
};

class ChildClass1: public BaseClass{
 ... some other functions
};

class Factory{  //factory
  public:
    static BaseClass * GetObject(int iter){
     if(iter==1){
      return ChildClass1;
     }
     else if(iter==2){
      return ChildClass1;
     }
     ....
    }
};
```

Understanding what would be the best design. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what problem you're having? Are you just asking for "best practice"? Best practice of *what*? Or do you have a more concrete problem? And what is the `iter` argument for in the `GetObject` function? Why do both `iter == 1` and `iter == 2` return object of `ChildClass1` (I assume you really mean `return new ChildClass1`)?

Comment: And I don't see any problem with calling a factory function from the base class, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I was thinking that calling factory from base class is correct coding according to Coding standards. 
~iter 1, or 2 is just to help in understanding that it is factory

Comment: There are no universal or general coding standards. Unless you are forced to follow some standards at work, you can do whatever you think is best.